# Removing leading \n while assaigning to a variable

Tags: shell, db2, newline

I have a DB2 query in a shell script which return an integer value, but I am unable to store it in a variable.

temp1=  echo `db2 -x "select max(id) from work.work_tb"`

I am getting this output when I run it, sh -x test.sh

- db2 -x select max(id) from work.work_tb
- echo 50
- temp1=
  50

So for some reason $temp1 is unable to get the value, I think its because the db2 query is returning value prefixed with \n. How do I get rid of the newline char and get the value to temp1?

Comment: 50 is coming in the next line
temp1= \n
50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not why.

```
temp1=`db2 -x "select max(id) from work.work_tb"`
```

Comment: works now,
I was using temp1=echo `db2 -x "select max(id) from work.work_tb"`

Comment: Actually, you have a space between `=` and `echo` in your question, which means that `$temp1` is getting set to nothing before running `echo`, leading to the output you saw.

Answer (score 0):

```
emp1=$(echo db2 -x "select max(id) from work.work_tb")
```

or using backticks

```
emp1=`echo db2 -x "select max(id) from work.work_tb"`
```

In general, to remove newlines, you can pass it to tools like `tr/sed` etc

```
... | tr -d "\n"
```